# I want to access a javascript variable in my HTML in my main node js file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

```
      function takePic(){
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
  }
```

So i have this function in a script tag nested in my HTML. I have a separate js file to start the server. My problem is I want to use this variable/data in my js file but I don't know how to access it.

Answer (score -1):

Hmmm sounds like you need to send the variable data across the internet from your html webpage to your node.js server. To do that you could look into using socket.io to send data back and forth.